# Docker Swarm vs. Docker Cluster

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-cloud

I created a swarm cluster via

```
docker-machine -d azure --swarm --swarm-master --swarm-discovery token://SWARM_CLUSTER_TOKEN my-swarm-master
```

and

```
docker-machine  -d azure--swarm --swarm-discovery token://SWARM_CLUSTER_TOKEN my-node-01
```

After that, I Logged into *cloud.docker.com* - but when I click on *Node Clusters* or *Nodes* I can't see my swarm.

So is **swarm** (via command line) and **cluster** (via cloud.docker.com) not the same thing? What's the difference and when should I use which one?

Edit:
Yes, my Azure subscription is added in cloud.docker.com under *Cloud Settings*.

Comment: By the way, you're using the legacy Swarm. Docker completely changed the way they do clustering in June with what's called "swarm mode". Legacy swarm and "swarm mode" are completely different at the API level and functional level. I suggest you learn "swarm mode" instead of legacy. https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are separate. The docker-machine commands you ran create a self hosted swarm that you manage yourself (from your first docker-machine command). The Docker Cloud creates an environment that's managed for you from the Docker infrastructure. Without access to that token used by Swarm, Docker Cloud won't know about the nodes in your Swarm.

Comment: "Without access to that token used by Swarm, Docker Cloud won't know about the nodes in your Swarm." - So can I pass the token to Docker Cloud? I think it has sth. to do with the *Bring your own node* and installing *Docker Cloud Agent*, hasn't it?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the Bring your own node token is completely different from the Docker Swarm token. While you use both similarly in your environment, they are completely different implementations and products. If you want a Docker product to manage your Swarm with a web UI, look into the Universal Control Plane (UCP).